# How to get a specific element from ArrayList?

Tags: android

I have a custom object `Coin`, it is made of 3 elements, who are all `Strings` and it is `Parcelable`.

Here's it's code:

```html
package com.example.vartotojas.heycrypto;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Coin implements Parcelable{

    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String change;

    public Coin(String name, String price, String change) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.change = change;
    }

    protected Coin(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        price = in.readString();
        change = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Coin> CREATOR = new Creator<Coin>() {
        @Override
        public Coin createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Coin(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Coin[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Coin[size];
        }
    };

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getChange() {
        return change;
    }

    public void setChange(String change) {
        this.change = change;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(price);
        dest.writeString(change);
    }
}
```

I am getting data for it from a OkHttp request:

```html
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    final String myResponce = response.body().string();

                    globalCoin.clear();

                    try {
                        JSONArray coins = new JSONArray(myResponce);
                        for(int i = 0; i < coins.length(); i++){
                            try {
                                JSONObject coin = coins.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = coin.getString("name");
                                String price = coin.getString("price_usd");
                                String change = coin.getString("percent_change_24h");

                                globalCoin.add(new Coin(name, price, change));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        refreshList();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I use it to populate a `ListView` in my first activity, but I need the same data for my 2nd one. I send it using this:

```html
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        
        //Other code cut out

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PortfolioActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("coins", globalCoin);

    }
```

In the second one I have an input, where a person can put in name, price and ammount after a button press. I need to find the same name element which was inputed from the `ArrayList` and get it's price, which is stored in the array. I was thinking of doing this:

```html
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String addName = data.getStringExtra("Name");
                String addPrice = data.getStringExtra("Price");
                String addAmmount = data.getStringExtra("Ammount");
                boolean pressed = data.getBooleanExtra("Pressed", FALSE);

                Intent intent2 = getIntent();
                coinList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("coins");
                int i = 0;
                for(i; coinList[i].name != addName && i <= coinList.size(); i++){
                }
                int addPrice = coinList[i].price;

            }
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){

            }
        }
    }
```

Yet, the code doesn't work. Why is that and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Use `Intent data` instead of `getIntent()` inside `onActivityResult`. And why are you returning a list (coinList) from other Activity ? It should be a single Object of Coin

Comment: @ADM Well, the `coinlist` has 100 coin names and their prices in it. When the person writes in the name and other data, I need to match both names (them to be the same) and get the price from the list. I don't know which name he wrote in and which price to get. So that's why I am getting the list. Am I making a mistake here?